# How do I make sql timestamp as column name?

Tags: mysql, sql

For instance:

```
select count(*) as (select date_sub(curdate(),interval 4 day)) 
from userinfo 
where createTime > (select date_sub(curdate(),interval 4 day));
```

This is not working. It says the syntax after 'as' is not correct. How do I make this work?

I want the result to be like this:

```
| |2016-01-14|
|-|----------|
|1|   1000   |
```

Comment: `select col1, ..., date_sub(curdate(),interval 4 day)) ... from ... `

Comment: No, I want to make date_sub(curdate(), interval 4day) as column name, not making it as a new column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With normal static query you cannot define column name as variable/subquery, but you could achieve it with dynamic SQL([prepared statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)):

```
SET @sql =
    CONCAT('select count(*) as `',(select date_sub(curdate(),interval 4 day)),'` from userinfo where createTime > (select date_sub(curdate(),interval 4 day));');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eacdd/3/2)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔════════════╗
║ 2016-01-14 ║
╠════════════╣
║          2 ║
╚════════════╝
```